# Multi-Column Combo box In visual Basic 6

Tags: combobox, vb6

```
 Call dbConnect
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
 rst.Open "SELECT referance_no,ship_mode FROM pre_mst_header ", connect, adOpenStatic
 rst.MoveFirst

 With Me.Combo1
    .clear
    Do
       .AddItem rst![referance_no]            
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
connect.Close
```

Regarding Vb6 combo box related issue. I have to display one data column using this code. but I want to display two data column. Eg:- Employee name with Employee Id number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate the columns into a string and use that with the combo box:

```
.AddItem CStr(rst![referance_no]) & ", " & CStr(rst![ship_mode])
```